# HTML\CSS: background image positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning, background-image, margin

i know we can position like this

```
background:url(../images/bg.jpg) top left;
```

but i want to do this

position the background to top center and move it 400 pixels to right... how can it be done

Comment: Let's wait for other browsers than Firefox to implement `calc()`, for example, I think this would work in Firefox: `background-position: top -moz-calc(50% - 400px);`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit:** This was stubborn to do in IE, so I've added some extra information to make it work there as well.*

***Edit2:**  Also used Microsoft's SuperPreview application to make this work in IE6.  Tested in FF3.6 and IE8, as well as IE6 in SuperPreview.*

Use the following CSS to nest your object:

```
body {
   margin:     0px;
   padding:    0px;
   text-align: center;
}

.parentDiv {
   margin:     0 auto;
   text-align: left;
   width:      2px; /* non-zero width */
}

.childDiv {
   position: relative;
   text-align: left;
   background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
   left:   399px !important; /* !important is not honored by IE6 */
   left:   600px;            /* overridden in all but IE6 */
   width:  300px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

You would have code similar to this (it's important to set `DOCTYPE` to strict):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
...
<div class=parentDiv><div class=childDiv>Child Content</div></div>
```

Change the value of `width` and `height` in childDiv based on your image.

Comment: this technique can work... and i would have done it myself but its not the solution... because you consider variable page heights and cross browser solution for div sizing especially for old browsers like ie5 and especially for my country where ie6 users are 22.5% of total

Comment: The answer I provided works in modern browsers.  If you need a specific solution for IE5/6, you should have stated that in your question.  In any case, it will be a very ugly hack to get this to work in those browsers.

Comment: Ok, I used a copy of Microsoft SuperPreview to test this in IE6.  It's not very flexible to test using this program, but it seems to achieve the desired effect.  Updating answer accordingly.

Comment: I used IETester to confirm this in IE 5.5 and IE 7.0 as well, however I am unable to resize the window to truly verify.  I can state that the position is exactly the same for each browser.

Answer (score 1):

This can't currently be done using classical `background-position` notation.

You would have to use JavaScript to calculate the element's width and set the position accordingly, or give the image some transparent space to the left to push it to the right. This might be the easiest solution.

Comment: @JCOC yup, that's a good idea too if you can work with a wrapper element

Comment: Or an extra element absolutely positioned to the center, with margin pushing it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with background-clip and background-origin, but that is in the future: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

A wrapper DIV or JavaScript should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to manipulate with <div> with positioning and z-index

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler with Javascript.

```
Pseudocode:
    Read the width of the enclosing element
    Compute its center
    Offset the center by desired amount of pixels
    Set this new value as the position of the background image
```